# Is Wolfram Workbench available in Eclipse Marketplace?

Tags: workbench, eclipse

Is Wolfram Workbench available in Eclipse Marketplace? What versions of Eclipse are compatible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wolfram Workbench is [not available](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/wolfram) in the Eclipse Marketplace.

You can install the Wolfram Workbench Plugin for Eclipse using the instructions [here](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/27221).

Eclipse 4.6 (Neon) or later are supported (I personally have the plugin installed on Eclipse 4.9).